# Mixing different models in one list in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models

I have three models: `paste`, `snippet` and `tutorial`. I want to show the newest of all of them mixed in one list, like this on the page:

```
<ul>
<li>Just a paste</li>
<li>The worst snippet ever (-10202343 kudos) (1 quadrillion comments)</li>
<li>Just another paste</li>
<li>Ruby on Rails tutorial (5 kudos) (2 comments)</li>
<li>Another snippet</li>
</ul>
```

Ordered by date. The problem is that I want to mix these three models in one list. All models have specific attributes (e.g. `snippet` and `tutorial` have tags, all have titles, `tutorial`s and `snippet`s have have kudos, only `paste` has a private boolean (so it should not be listed)).

How can I do some kind of mixing these different models in my view?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would solve this at the database-level, introducing a PublishedItem, and the PublishedItem then points to either a Paste, a Snippet or a Tutorial. That would solve creating the list of items: just select the 5 latest published items. And from a published item you can then find the correct item, and show it.

Comment: I definitely agree this should be done at database level, but are you suggesting that the PublishedItem should have its own table? That is just wrong! That would introduce all sorts of trouble. Instead create a database view selecting all the common columns from each model. Then let the PublishedItem use the view instead of a table. Also create a polymorphic association between PublishedItem and the other models. But don't do this manually, let the listable gem do all the trouble.

Comment: A view is indeed one way to solve this. Single table inheritance is the generally adviced rails way, but this can sometimes introduce other problems if the objects have very different attributes. So I still believe a good alternative is Multiple Table Inheritance, which in my view, is not _just wrong_. A good article about can be found [here](http://techspry.com/ruby_and_rails/multiple-table-inheritance-in-rails-3/). HTH. Note please that this is not a _new_ concept, I have used this approach many items outside of rails.

Comment: Well of course, if the models are related is some way, then MTI is a very good solution. Absolutely nothing wrong with that! But if you want to show completely unrelated models in a mixed list, the view approach makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Grab a list of the "events" or whatever in your controller

```
@events = Paste.find_all
@events << Snippet.find(:order => "votes", :limit => 1)
@events << Tutorial.find_all
```

then in your view

```
<%
    @events.each do |event|
      display_snippet(event) if event.class == Snippet
      display_tutorial(event) if event.class == Tutorial
    end   
%>
```

there are a few ways to handle the view part of it, but it seems pretty straight forward.  In this example, display_snippet and display_event would be helper methods but it might be cleaner to use partials.

Comment: that is WAY too much logic in the view

Comment: Matt, it's just a loop and a couple of if statements to control the display.....

What would you suggest?